# Works in Graph Explorer, but not POST

Tags: php, facebook

Goal: publish a post to a Facebook Page as the Page, not myself.

Used to do this via REST, but FB deprecated this.

Using their Graph Explorer tool, I can send a POST request to this url:

```
.../v2.7/{pageid}/feed?message={message}&access_token={appid}|{token}
```

When I check the page, the post appears as expected.  However, when I put the post into a PHP call a la:

```
<?php

    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/$page_id/feed/" ;
    $ch  = curl_init($url) ;

    $postString = http_build_query($data , '' , '&' ) ;

    curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POST , 1 ) ;
    curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString ) ;
    curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ) ;

    $response = curl_exec( $ch ) ;
    curl_close( $ch ) ;

    echo $response ;
?>
```

What I get it this error message:

```
{
    "error":
    {
        "message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action",
        "type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"G1fXPByqJ16"
    }
}
```

Why am I getting permissions errors in one place, but not the other?

Comment: Graph Explorer is using the accesstoken specified higher up in the page and not the one you specify. You need to use a page access token and not an app access token

Comment: My page-access token doesn't have publish_pages.  When I click "Request publish_pages", there's a brief appearance of a dialog box that dies quickly, and nothing appears to change.  How do I generate a permanent page access token and grant publish_pages permission on it for my app?

Comment: The user has to grant the permissions, and then you go get the page token using the user access token.